# Why isn't a .post and .html call able to compare in an if(condition) in jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

The following script has been created to test if the value of a db field has changed and if so then reload the page and if not, alert the user that the change has not happened.

The alert is just to see what is being returned by the .post function.

The auto_refresh works fine as i need it to check every 5 seconds, when the if() condition is set to '==' the page alert shows and if it is set to '!=' the page continually reloads.

jQuery.post is getting the db field data but it doesn't seem to be able to compare the 2 values correctly.

any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function(){
    $.post("/index.php/listen", function(data) {
          if($('#slide').html() != data)
            {
               window.location.reload()
            }
            else
            {
               alert('its the same'+ data);
            }
          });
    }, 5000);
```

EDITED

Rather than trying to parse raw data, why not pass HTML from the $.post() like:

```
<p>4</p>
```

Then the jQuery inserts the the replaces the p tag with the new version from the $.post()
because the html is passed on there is no white space and the comparison can be made correctly.

Comment: Did you compare the values on the console ? Write `console.log($('#slide').html(), data)`.

Comment: Use a debugger (there's [no excuse](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/03/no-excuse.html) not to) and set a breakpoint on the comparison, then inspect `data` and the return value of `.html()` (ideally, put it in a var first to make life easy). There's no substitute for actual debugging work. Presumably `.html()` is returning something *slightly* different from `data` (whitespace before or after, that sort of thing).

Comment: white space is being added but missed that until it was pointed out, thanks. i have tried variables but the same results come back, i need a way of striping out the white space i think.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is very safe to compare the new value with an html. Some browsers might add spaces or unwanted chars. I'd try to save the old value in an input of type hidden and use the `.val()` or, event better, in a variable. It depends of your scenario.

Comment: "Some browsers might add spaces or unwanted chars". Do you have some source/support for this ?

Comment: No really, but have been there. Of course, it also depends the element in which the text is being saved.

Comment: both firefox and chrome add white space around the html in many elements including inputs, thanks for the heads up i didn't even look for the white space. a solution will come i am sure.

Answer (score 0):

If $('#slide').html() == data

then that means that the conditional failed, it was not equal, so it showed the alert.

The problem is that the data variable might come back with a few extra white spaces. If I were you, I'd try to parse a small section of the data variable, and a small section of the html in slider and compare those values.

Like if slider has something within a p tag or an input value, compare it to the data to see if it has that same value returned in that p tag or input value, then replace all the whitespaces with an empty string just to be safe.

Btw, try not to use alerts since you can't really know for sure if there is an extra whitespace. Try to use something like "debugger" if using IE with visual studios, or console.log when using chrome or firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing two html strings: one is serialized from the DOM, and another is from a server response.

There's no guarantee that the two strings will **ever** be the same! Think about it: the same rendered html can have many string differences. E.g. `<a href="/file">  click </a>` and `<a href="http://example.org/file">click</a>` are both the same HTML, but different strings.

You can take two different approaches here:

1. You can create some kind of canonicalization routine that guarantees that two html fragments you consider "the same" will have the same string form. Run both html fragments through this routine, then compare.
2. You can manage versions more explicitly.

   1. Include some kind of version indicator:

      1. You can use the `ETAG` header (which means you can take advantage of http caching mechanisms).
      2. You can include some kind of version number in the html itself (maybe in a `data-version` attribute), and compare those.
   2. You can keep the html string from your server separately and compare against that.